# How can primitive data types have access to prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How primitive data types (strings, numbers etc.) have access to methods like .toString(). We can even access to their proto's by typing variable.**proto** but they are not object.

Comment: You'll get an idea for this link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript automatically converts primitives to String objects, so that it's possible to use String object methods for primitive strings.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String